# Spring kafka re-create Kafka Stream Topology in runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application that is based on spring boot, spring-kafka and kafka-streams.
When application starts up, it creates kafka streams topology with default list of topics.
What I need to do is edit/recreate topology in runtime. For example, when application already running, there is new topic name comes and I want to add this topic to my topology.
Currently I'm thinking about somehow to delete existing topology, close and clean up KafkaStreams, run logic where I create topology but with new topic name and start KafkaStreams again. I don`t want to restart my application. 
Can someone suggest me how to do this in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 1 solution. 
I extend StreamsBuilderFactoryBean:

```
@Bean(name = DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
@Primary
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder(KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfigs) {
    return new DynamicStreamsBuilderFactoryBean(kStreamsConfigs);
}

public static class DynamicStreamsBuilderFactoryBean extends StreamsBuilderFactoryBean {

    private StreamsBuilder instance;

    public DynamicStreamsBuilderFactoryBean(final KafkaStreamsConfiguration streamsConfig) {
        super(streamsConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized StreamsBuilder createInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new StreamsBuilder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void stop() {
        instance = null;
        super.stop();
    }
}
```

And when I build topology, I, instead of using StreamsBuilder, use StreamsBuilderFactoryBean#getObject():

```
@Component
```

public class DynamicStream {

```
private final StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean;

public void init() {
    StreamsBuilder builder = streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getObject();
        //build topology
}

//call this method when stream reconfiguration is needed
public void reinitialize() {
    streamsBuilderFactoryBean.stop();
    init();
    streamsBuilderFactoryBean.start();
}
```

}